# Bootstrap v.4.1 - Icon inside input breaks

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, angular-reactive-forms

I am currently working with Angular 6 and the newest Version of **Bootstrap v4.1**
Now i try to build a reactive form with icons inside of input forms. Since there is not really a way in bootstrap to put icons on the left side of input - I need to hack it myself. But this is not really working. Lets have a closer look:

### usecase1

When there does no error msg apper - it looks all fine and as expected:
[image]

### usecase2

But when the form changes and the msg appers - the icon breaks from the form:
[image]

### Code

html:

```
<form [formGroup]="registerForm">
          <div class="form-group required">
            <label class="control-label">Email address:</label>
            <input formControlName="username" type="email" class="form-control">
            <span *ngIf="isFieldInvalid('username')" class="form-control-feedback-invalid-username"><fa class="danger" [name]="'ban'"></fa></span>
            <span *ngIf="isFieldValid('username')" class="form-control-feedback-valid-username"><fa class="danger" [name]="'check'"></fa></span>

            <span *ngIf="isFieldValidWithErrorType('username', 'required')" [ngClass]="displayFieldCss('username', 'required')">Username has to be set.</span>
            <span *ngIf="isFieldValidWithErrorType('username', 'email')" [ngClass]="displayFieldCss('username', 'email')">Email should have right pattern.</span>
          </div>

      <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="control-label">Password:</label>
        <input formControlName="password" type="password" class="form-control">
        <span *ngIf="isFieldInvalid('password')" class="form-control-feedback-invalid-password"><fa class="danger" [name]="'ban'"></fa></span>
        <span *ngIf="isFieldValid('password')" class="form-control-feedback-valid-password"><fa class="danger" [name]="'check'"></fa></span>

        <span *ngIf="isFieldValidWithErrorType('password', 'required')" [ngClass]="displayFieldCss('password', 'required')">Password has to be set.</span>

      </div>
        </form>
```

The important class is `form-control-feedback-username/password`. It looks as follows in the css:

```
.form-control-feedback-invalid-username {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  right: 25px;
  top: 77px;
  color: red;
  line-height: 34px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.form-control-feedback-valid-username {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  right: 25px;
  top: 77px;
  color: #35ef5f;
  line-height: 34px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: the error text is pulling the inputs down but because the icons have a position absolute they stay in the same position.... you can either make the span message `position: absolute` or add a position relative to `.form-group`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With trial and error and a advice from @marco gomes i figured it out how the icon stays in line:

```
.form-group {
  position: relative;
  .form-control-feedback-invalid-username {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 40px;
    right: 10px;
    color: red;
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  .form-control-feedback-valid-username {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 40px;
    right: 10px;
    color: #35ef5f;
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  .form-control-feedback-invalid-password {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 40px;
    right: 10px;
    color: red;
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  .form-control-feedback-valid-password {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 40px;
    right: 10px;
    color: #35ef5f;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
```